# Colored Variables Not Working

Tags: javascript

Please help. I have been coding my  Website. And I have tried to make the text for my website red, but only a certain part using Javascript.

```
document.getElementById("derping").innerHTML = "You have: " + derp + " Derple Points";
```

I want to make "derp" Red. I tried:

```
document.getElementById("derping").innerHTML = "You have: " + derp.fontcolor("red") + " Derple Points";
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Thanks, Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change an element's font color after it was created, for example:

```
document.body.style.color = 'red';
```

---

However, in your case, I'd suggest having a class `.red` and wrapping your text with a `span` of this class:

```
document.getElementById("derping").innerHTML = "You have: <span class='red'>" + derp + "</span> Derple Points";
```

And in your css:

```
.red{ color: red; }
```

---

If you don't want to change your css:

```
document.getElementById("derping").innerHTML = "You have: <span style='color:red'>" + derp + "</span> Derple Points";
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't use CSS... (It's because of various problems...I'll try uploading css...), Thanks Though.

Comment: @Mario1luigi9 Ok, then, try the 3rd solution I provided.